# How to split scraped bad html with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, text-processing

below I have html chunk that I  have extracted with BeautifulSoup

HTML:

```
<div class="adr">
                                         940 Walton Street<br/>Salt Lake City, UT 84116                                        </div>
```

I want to split its text and assign them as below:

```
address = '940 Walton Street'
city = 'Salt Lake City'
state = 'UT'
zipcode = '84116'
```

So far I managed to extract it as below but can't figure out a way to assign address part.

**1st Attempt:**

```
print(soup.get_text(separator=" ").strip())
```

will give me the output below

```
940 Walton Street Salt Lake City, UT 84116
```

**2nd Attempt:**

```
textTmp = soup.text
textStripped = re.split('"([A-Z])"', textTmp)
print('+' + textStripped[0] + '+')
```

gives me the output below, (with all the empty spaces)

```
                                940 Walton StreetSalt Lake City, UT 84116
```

**3rd Attempt**

```
''.join(personAddress.find('br').next_siblings)
```

and this gives me this output but not the first part:

```
Salt Lake City, UT 84116
```

Actually this one is good, I will parse this in to City, State and zipcode  but from here I can't access the first part (the address part)

I'm stuck. Can someone help me to solve this? or at least show me some pointers?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `contents` and do some string manipulation on that.
contents[0] is first text before break tag and contents[2] is text after break tag.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html='''<div class="adr">
                                         940 Walton Street<br/>Salt Lake City, UT 84116                                        </div>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
address=soup.select_one('.adr').contents[0].strip()
citystatezip=soup.select_one('.adr').contents[2].strip().split(',')
city=citystatezip[0]
statezip=citystatezip[1].strip().split(" ")
state=statezip[0]
zip=statezip[1]

print("address="+address,"City=" +city,"state="+state,"Zip="+zip)
```

Output:

```
address=940 Walton Street City=Salt Lake City state=UT Zip=84116
```

There might some regex solution as well however I can't figure out this.

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη : That is not `regex` solutions.That is string manipulation only :)

Comment: there's no need for regex if we have very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

Please excuse if this is a poor solution, I am new to python and have never used the soup library but from what I can see.

Where you have the code

```
''.join(personAddress.find('br').next_siblings)
```

if you replace next_siblings to previous_siblings then you are able to access things before the

so instead it would be this

```
''.join(personAddress.find('br').previous_siblings)
```

also to clean up the html string you could use the prettify() method

```
input = """<div class="adr">
                                         940 Walton Street<br/>Salt Lake City, UT 84116                                        </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(input, 'html.parser')

soup = BeautifulSoup(soup.prettify(), 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div class="adr">
                                         940 Walton Street<br/>Salt Lake City, UT 84116                                        </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'adr'}):
    item = item.get_text(",", strip=True).split(',')
    item.extend(item.pop(-1).strip().split())
    print("Address: {}\nCity: {}\nState: {}\nZip: {}".format(
        item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3]))
```

Output:

```
Address: 940 Walton Street
City: Salt Lake City
State: UT
Zip: 84116
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex + simplified_scrapy solution

```
import re
from simplified_scrapy.simplified_doc import SimplifiedDoc 
html='''<div class="adr">940 Walton Street<br/>Salt Lake City, UT 84116</div>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
div = doc.getElement('div',attr='class',value='adr') # obtain the DIV

items = re.split('<br\s*/>|,',div.html) # use regex split innerHtml
cz =items[2].strip().split(' ')
print ("Address: {}\nCity: {}\nState: {}\nZip: {}".format(items[0],items[1],cz[0],cz[1]))
```